# impute data with condition (4 levels) in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have two different variables in my data. first one: vein size (there are NAs).
Second variable is: procedure site (c=(1,2,3,4))

I want to impute different value to vein size based on different procedure site. I tried if else, but it wasn't successful. e.g.: if procedure site is 1 or 2, impute 3; if procedure site is 3, impute 4; if procedure site is 4, impute 5.I am new to this field. Any help is much appreciated!

```
vein.size<-(3,3,3,NA,NA,NA)
procedure.site<-(1,2,2,3,4,4)
df<-cbind(vein.size,procedure.site)
```

My expected output is:

```
vein.size<-(3,3,3,4,5,5)
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use chain of `ifelse` statement or try `case_when` from `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(output = case_when(is.na(vein.size) & procedure.site %in% 1:2 ~ 3, 
                            is.na(vein.size) & procedure.site == 3 ~ 4, 
                            is.na(vein.size) & procedure.site == 4 ~ 5, 
                            TRUE ~ vein.size))

#  vein.size procedure.site output
#1         3              1      3
#2         3              2      3
#3         3              2      3
#4        NA              3      4
#5        NA              4      5
#6        NA              4      5
```

**data**

```
vein.size<-c(3,3,3,NA,NA,NA)
procedure.site<-c(1,2,2,3,4,4)
df<-data.frame(vein.size,procedure.site)
```

Comment: hi Ronak: thanks I think both comments are useful. but how to only mutate or transform for missing value. all the data in vein.size changed after I used these two codes! thanks

Comment: See update answer to change value where `vein.size` is `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lookup table and then merge:

```
# your data
vein.size <- c(3,3,3,NA,NA,NA)
procedure.site <- c(1,2,2,3,4,4)
your_df <- data.frame(vein.size = vein.size, 
                      procedure.site = procedure.site)

# the lookup table
lookup_df <- data.frame(
  procedure.site = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  imputation     = c(3, 3, 4, 5)
)

# result
merge(your_df, lookup_df, by='procedure.site')
```

Which gives:

```
  procedure.site vein.size imputation
1              1         3          3
2              2         3          3
3              2         3          3
4              3        NA          4
5              4        NA          5
6              4        NA          5
```